# How do I toggle the color of html text and background with a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm am currently learning to code at school and need to code 3 `JavaScript` elements into a website I have made. I have already completed 2 of 3 elements however I am struggling with the third. in order to make the website more accessible for visually impaired people I have decided to try and code a button that upon being clicked will change the background color from black to white and the text (h1, p and li) from purple to white I have already set the `background-color` and text colors in the body as opposed to in a style format. And then another button that changes the colors back to original. I would really appreciate some help as I am felling stuck as every solution leads to another dead end. Thanks for reading and possibly helping.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where **exactly** are you stuck?

Comment: what is the color u want to have when clicking the button ?

Comment: @salaheddinemakdour  I would like the colour to be black. I have tried searching other forums and using basic tags attached to buttons such as "document.h1-style='color:black'"

Comment: i've posted a simple answer, hoe it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript function to toggle the state of the website, which in turn loads a different stylesheet by changing the `href` attribute of the `<style>` tag.

```js
function toggleHighContrast() {
    if (document.getElementById("stylesheet").getAttribute("href") === "/styles/main.css") {
        document.getElementById("stylesheet").setAttribute("href", "/styles/contrast.css");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("stylesheet").setAttribute("href", "/styles/main.css");
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleHighContrast()">Toggle High Contrast</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand which colors you wanted but here is an example of changing the background-color from black to white and the text color from purple to black.
HTML

```
<body style="background-color: black;">
 <h1 class="text" style="color:purple;"> This is the header text </h1>
 <p class="text" style="color:purple;"> This is the paragraph </p>

 <button onclick="changeTheme();">Click me to change the theme</button
</body>
```

Javascript

```
let changeTheme = function(){
  document.querySelector('.text').style.color = 'black';
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, using your method would I be able to use a reset button in order to restore the website back to the original themes?

Comment: yes just make another button and another function that changes the styles of the background and the texts to the original color